# system profiling - usage information of shared libraries

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-libraries, perf, intel-vtune, oprofile

Is there any way to know which library files are being used by which process (or by how many number of process) in some amount of time.

Can V-Tune or perf or OProfile be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to know which library files are being used by which process (or by how many number of process)

You can take a snapshot by `cat /proc/*/maps > /tmp/snapshot` and then use `grep` and `wc` to answer your question.

If you want to monitor the system for some period of time, you could take the snapshot every second or so.

> Can V-Tune or perf or OProfile be used for this?

You can do `perf record -a`, then `perf script -D` and look for `PERF_RECORD_MMAP` events.

Answer (score 2):

> At any moment, one can list all shared-libraries within the **process map** of a particular process-pid

```
cat /proc/<pid>/maps | grep <name of library>
```

[image: process maps]

---

> Also one can check the **list of running processes** that have opened a particular shared library

```
lsof <path-to-shared-library-file>
```

[image: lsof shared lib]